# How can I open a json file in modules in python

Tags: python, json, path

This is my project structure

[image: my project structure]

I am opening `input.json` inside `user_input.get_input.py` file using the following code:

```py
open('..\\data\\input.json', 'w')
```

When I run `get_input.py` file, it works perfectly. But when I run `run.py` file it shows me this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\data\\input.json'
```

I tried using full path too, but no success!

Comment: Using the full path should work.

Comment: Although using the full path would work, it of course means the script will only run on computers that have everything in the same place - OP trying to use a relative path has the right idea, but the wrong implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the working directory of the main script you start is the working directory for the ones that you import as well. You can either set the working directory to be `user_input` in the run configuration in PyCharm, or change the path to `data\\input.json` when running from `run.py`.

If you want the relative path independent of working directory in `get_input.py`, try this:

```
from pathlib import Path

open(Path(__file__).parent.parent / 'data\\input.json', 'w')
```

The `parent` of `Path(__file__)` is the directory the script itself is in, and *its* parent is one level up. This would also work:

```
from pathlib import Path

open(Path(__file__).parent / '..\\data\\input.json', 'w')
```

If you don't like computing the relative path from various modules, you could also consider giving your application a global root path, accessible from its various modules, which is best depends on the exact application.

Comment: I got the idea now. I added `print(os.getcwd())` and saw what happening when running `run.py` and `get_input.py`. when running `run.py` I need to `open('egybest\\data\\input.json', 'w'), since `egybest` folder is in the same scope as `run.py`. Thanks for the explanation!